# fix annoying glitch on website with repeating background (CSS)

Tags: html, css, background, scroll, repeat

How would i fix this issue. If you jam the main part of my code with text that appears on the site so much that you finally get a scrollbar. Once you've scrolled down the top banner repeats itself. If you do it again with more text the same thing repeats multiple times.

Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>MC serverlist</title>
</head>

<body id="servers">

<div id="maincontainer">

<ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="index.php" id="servers_nav">SERVERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="skins.php" id="skins_nav">SKINS</a></li>
    <li><a href="resource-packs.php" id="resource-packs_nav">RESOURCE PACKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="builds.php" id="builds_nav">BUILDS</a></li>
    <li><a href="mods.php" id="mods_nav">MODS</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum.php" id="forum_nav">FORUM</a></li>
</ul>



Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #A3A3A3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7D7D7D, #7D7D7D 50px, transparent 57px,     transparent 140%);
}
#maincontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 960px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: ridge;
  border-color: #919191;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding-top: 6px;
}

ul li {
float:left;
margin-right: 12px;
border: groove;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #969696;
}

ul li a {
display:block;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
height: 38px;
background-color:#7D7D7D;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 37px;
color: #EDEDED;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: impact;
font-size: 1.8em;
}

ul li:hover {
float:left;
margin-right: 12px;
border: ridge;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #969696;
}

ul li a:hover {
color: white;
}

ul li a:active {
background-color: black;
}
```

Try it yourself on localhost, not in the online code testers. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's not a glitch

It's expected behavior. [The default for `background-repeat`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat) is to `repeat`, so this...

```
html, body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7D7D7D, #7D7D7D 50px, transparent 57px,     transparent 140%);
}
```

...will repeat unless you state...

```
html, body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

...every time it reaches the end of the image size.

Comment: HAHA Thanks, I feel dumb i havent thought of that :P

Comment: Hey, we can all miss the "obvious" sometimes.